# IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run through the loop I have below but I get this index

```
error:IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12
```

The only important thing to know about the variables is the the length of element is 12.

I have already tried to break the code once it reaches 12 but I still got the same error

```
for element in group1:
        count = 0
        while count < len(element):
            if element.columns[count] == "No Experience(REM)" or "No Experience(NREM)":
                element1 = Project().butterWorth(element)
                element2 = Project().fourierTransform(element1)
                class1group1.append(element2)
                count = count + 1
```

I expect the loop to go through each value in element without having an error

Comment: you should try `while count < len(element.columns)`

Comment: This will have me append all the column values and not just the column values with "No Experience(REM) " and "No Experience(NREM)"

Comment: what is `element` ? Can you post the full code

Comment: Element is a data frame of 150000 x 12 matrix. Each of the 12 columns has a name. Also, the line where the error occurs is at the if statement

Comment: The second element is 150,000 x 9 and these are the only two elements in the group1 array